# UITabBar – setItems:animated: Crashes

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

So I have a UITabView Controller that was created in interface builder. The title and image properties of UITabBarItem were set in IB. A Tab Bar Controller object is present in the xib and all necessary connections are made. I am able to call simple commands such as

[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

Everything works fine but when I set the 'items' property, I crash. Maybe I am having a memory management problem?

Here is the crashing code:

```
NSMutableArray *modifiedItems = [[tabBarController.tabBar items] mutableCopy];  
[modifiedItems removeObjectAtIndex:2];  
NSArray *newItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:modifiedItems];  
-->[tabBarController.tabBar setItems:newItems animated:NO];
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'
*** Call stack at first throw:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02b9bb99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02ceb40e objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02b54238 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02b541aa +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
4   UIKit                               0x005f7019 -[UITabBar setItems:animated:] + 2037
5   Zag Map                             0x00003422 -[ZagMapAppDelegate iPodTouchRemoval] + 270
6   Zag Map                             0x00002eea -[ZagMapAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 551
7   UIKit                               0x003faf80 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1252
8   UIKit                               0x003fd3b0 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 346
9   UIKit                               0x004073ec -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958
10  UIKit                               0x003ffb3c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
11  UIKit                               0x004049bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
12  GraphicsServices                    0x03357822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
13  CoreFoundation                      0x02b7cff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
14  CoreFoundation                      0x02add807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
15  CoreFoundation                      0x02adaa93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
16  CoreFoundation                      0x02ada350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
17  CoreFoundation                      0x02ada271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
18  UIKit                               0x003fcc6d -[UIApplication _run] + 625
19  UIKit                               0x00408af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
20  Zag Map                             0x00002ca0 main + 102
21  Zag Map                             0x00002c31 start + 53
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

My NSArray and NSMutableArray appear to be fine considering they came straight out of the functioning UITabBar. It returned three objects, then two. I hope I'm just overlooking something stupid here. Any ideas I would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you get exception message? That would really help I think.

Comment: Click on "breakpoints" and then "build and debug". When it crashes there will be a more detailed error which will tell you with more information whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message tells you exactly what is wrong:

> 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Set the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had seen the same code used successfully by others.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllersCopy = [[tabBarController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
[viewControllersCopy removeObjectAtIndex:2];
NSArray *modifiedViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:viewControllersCopy];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:modifiedViewControllers animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that-

```
 tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; // set index according to your requirement
```